# python - ordinal value - list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python

what i want to do is take a string and for each character make the ordinal value 1 more from the value it has.

```
myinput=input("Message : ")

mylist =list(myinput) #convert to list in order to take each character

for character in mylist:
    mylist[character]+=ord(mylist[character])+1
print(character)
```

The problem is with the "ord(mylist[character])**+1**"

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you all for the help!I wanted a solution as close as my code.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to ask - hope this wasn't homework :)

Comment: Kind of,but i tried it a lot!

Comment: Actually, the problem is with `mylist[character]` -- you can't use a `str` as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems here. First, you're mixing up list indices and list elements. Second, you didn't convert back to a character (I'm assuming you want characters, not numbers). Third, you're adding to the existing value.

One way:

```
for i range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = chr(ord(mylist[i])+1)
```

Another way:

```
for i, character in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = chr(ord(character)+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are looking for the next:

```
>>> m = raw_input('Message:')
Message:asdf
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c) + 1) for c in m)
'bteg'
```

Notes:

- use `raw_input` when you need to get string input from a user;
- `ord` convert character to integer, `chr` - vise versa;
- `... for c in m` syntax is a generator expression. It is also used for [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Nicely Pythonic, so +1, but possibly not too clear to the OP at his current level of understanding.

Comment: Actually, if you don't use `[]`, it's a generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for character in mylist:
    mylist[character]+=ord(mylist[character])+1
```

(where character is a list index and therefore invalid), you probably want:

```
mylist = [ord(character) + 1 for character in mylist]
```

Or a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Note to OP: this is called a "list comprehension" and it's a very handy tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

def  ordsum(astring, tablesize):
    sum = 0
    for num in range(len(astring)):
        sum = sum + ord(astring[num])

```
return sum
```

Comment: Please explain why this works so others can understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
myinput = input() # use raw_input() in Python 2
myinput = map(lambda ch: chr(ord(ch) + 1), myinput)
# or list comp.
myinput = [chr(ord(ch) + 1) for ch in myinput]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate directly over a string, you do not have to make it a list first.  If your end goal is to have a new string, you can do this:

```
myinput=input("Message : ")

result = []
for character in myinput:
    result.append( chr( ord( character ) + 1 )
mynewstring = ' '.join(result)
```